# how to use an Activity twice in an App in android

Tags: android, android-activity

in my app i have an **Activity A** with buttons **B1,B2,B3** the three are used to move to other activities such as **B1 to B**, **B2 to C** and **B3 to D** respectively.

In another **activity X** i am using a condition, if the condition is true i moving to 
**Activity A**, but here by using **Button B1** i want to move back to **Activity X**.

my question is, is it possible to use a single activity twice in an app for various operations or should i have to create a separate activity and layout files...

please tell me friends.....

Answer (score 0):

You can start multiple instances of the same activity, yes. Be aware that when your user presses the back button, they'll go back to whatever launched **this instance**, not what launched the first instance.

Comment: sorry friend, i am not asking about back button.